# devextream tag-box can we add custom row without checkbox in angular

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am using angular 10 and devextream tag-box with checkbox, **now I want to add custom div on top and bottom of the data row of the selection that will not checkbox** any suggestion how can i achieve that.

```
 <div class="dx-field-value">
            <dx-tag-box
            [dataSource]="products"
            displayExpr="Name"
            valueExpr="Id"
            [showSelectionControls]="true"
            [maxDisplayedTags]="3"
            itemTemplate="item">
            <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'item'">
              
                <div style="display:inline-block">{{data.Name}}</div>
            </div>
        </dx-tag-box>
        </div>
```

Comment: what you mean by data row?  you mean selected items inside the tag box you want add custom template at top and bottom of selected item?

Comment: yes custom text without a checkbox on top of the selected (item) row

Answer (score 0):

can you disable `showSelectionControls` and try:

```
 <div class="dx-field-value">
  <dx-tag-box
    [dataSource]="products"
    displayExpr="Name"
    valueExpr="Id"
    [showSelectionControls]="false"
    [maxDisplayedTags]="3"
    itemTemplate="item">
    <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'item'">
      <div>TOP</div>
      <div>{{data.Name}}</div>
      <div>BOTTOM</div>
    </div>
  </dx-tag-box>
</div>
```

[TagBox - Customize Item Appearance](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/TagBox/Customize_Item_Appearance/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing but in my scenario I need a checkbox for the data item (with showSelectionControls=true) and for the top and bottom row without a checkbox

Comment: I cant figure out your idea yet, are you mean you don't want this text to be clickable just select from checkboxes at the center?
https://ibb.co/Rj0MhDD

Comment: Thanks for your input, the scenario is like we have 10 items so I need to show 12 items first and last without a checkbox, so top one and bottom row text should be custom it is not part of the data (the item of the list)

Comment: can you try grouping as a workaround check this: 
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/TagBox/GroupedItems/Angular/Light/